# Sort array of arrays according to child arrays count

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of arrays. The child arrays contains objects. How can I sort these child arrays in the parent array so that they sorted with the first array being the one which contains the most objects down to the last child array which contains the least objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case is enough to implement a simple comparator:

```
NSArray* sortedArray= [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    return [obj2 count] - [obj1 count];
}];
```

**Further explanation**

*NSComparisonResult* is this enum:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,             // 0
   NSOrderedDescending        // +1
};
```

So subtracting the two arrays counts you get the right order, avoiding to write the usual boring if-then-else. For readability and to don't confuse ideas to beginners I add the long version here:

```
NSArray* sortedArray= [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    if([obj1 count] > [obj2 count])
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    if([obj1 count] < [obj2 count])
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

**Alternative**

Also using a sort descriptor with the *@count* collection operator is elegant:

```
NSSortDescriptor* descriptor= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"@count" ascending: NO];
NSArray* sortedArray= [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[ descriptor ]];
```

Comment: You don't need a custom one. Just `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:YES]`.

Comment: @KenThomases The key should be @"@count" , and the order shouldn't be ascending, he wants them sorted starting from the longer one.

Comment: "@count" is a collection operator, not a key, and is not what I meant. He wants to sort by the "count" property of each element in his (outer) array. The fact that the elements are themselves arrays is irrelevant beyond the fact that they support a "count" property. You're correct about the ascending parameter.

Comment: @KenThomases But *NSArray* doesn't have a *count* property, sorting an array with that sort descriptor will cause a crash.

Comment: Of course `NSArray` has a `count` property. Properties don't necessarily have to be "declared properties" using `@property`. Just the existence of a getter method establishes the existence of a property. The existence of `-[NSArray count]` means `NSArray` has a `count` property.

Comment: It simply crashes if you do that way. I also make this distinction because otherwise also methods used for side effects would be considered properties. For example also *NSAlert*'s *runModal* would be considered a property, and I don't think it's correct.